# how can i get value of textbox on radio button's change event in cloning?

Tags: jquery

i have done cloning of radio button and textbox .so now i have many text boxes and radio buttons  on change event of radio button i need value of its text box

```
for (var j = 0; j < sJsonData[1].data.length; j++) {
   var abc = xyz.clone(true, true);
   abc.find('input[type="text"][name="textbox1"]').attr('id', j);
   abc.find('input[type="radio"][name="radio"]').attr('id', j);
}
$('input[type="radio"][name="radio"]').change(function () {
   var paying_amount = $(this).parent()
                              .children()
                              .find('input[type="text"][name="textbox1"]')
                              .val();
});
```

how to get value of text box on change event of radio button ?

Comment: Sorry but how do you maintain such terribly formated code?

Comment: Can you possibly set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your code demonstrating the issue, please? And what is `xyz`?

Comment: i am making clone of that div and appending to its upper div

Comment: xyz= $("#trdisbursment");

Comment: i m doing cloning of divs that have a table <tr> <td>radiobutton</td><td>textbox</td> </tr>  so now i have many tr with many radio button and text boxes. now i need  value of textbox on change event of radio button of perticular <tr>

Comment: with $(this).val() it give value of radio button but i need value of textbox so i m using $(this).parent()
                              .children()
                              .find('input[type="text"][name="textbox1"]')
                              .val();

Comment: did you try like this $(this).closest('tr').children().find('input[type="text"][name="textbox1"]').val(); ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid using same 'id' for many elements in the document. Use 'class' instead. You can use this as an alternative,

```
for (var j = 0; j < sJsonData[1].data.length; j++) {
   var abc = xyz.clone(true, true);
   abc.find('input[type="text"][name="textbox1"]').data('id', j);
   abc.find('input[type="radio"][name="radio"]').data('id', j);

   //abc.find('input[type="text"][name="textbox1"]').attr('id', j);
   //abc.find('input[type="radio"][name="radio"]').attr('id', j);
}
```

You need to use 'on' because you are adding elements dynamically,

```
$('#parent').on("change", 'input[type="radio"][name="radio"]', function(){
   var id = $(this).data('id');
   var paying_amount = $('input[type="text"]').filter('[data-id="'+id+'"]').val();
});
```

Comment: `live()` has been deprecated since jQuery 1.7 and was removed in 1.9. Use `on()` instead.

Comment: what is $('#parent') ?

Comment: $('#parent') is just a static element that holds all the radio, textboxes. In your case you can use $('table.some_class')

Comment: i m using div on witch i m appending all value as parent but its not working. it returning undefined value

Comment: can you make quick jsfiddle? so that we can understand the html structure you are using..

Comment: var id = $(this).data('id'); is also returning undefined value i guess it taking value of parent div

Comment: nope. var id will get the 'input[type="radio"][name="radio"]' value. So clearly the problem is are here where you are assinging the data value abc.find('input[type="radio"][name="radio"]').data('id', j);

Comment: are you sure 'input[type="radio"][name="radio"]' is direct next child to 'abc'? if not abc.find('input[type="radio"][name="radio"]').data('id', j); wont work

Comment: I just looked at the html structure. Try change your code like this 'tehriproject.find(' to 'tehriproject.children().find('